# hexadecimal in typedef enum in C

Tags: c, enums

I was searching for the reason behind using hexadecimal in `typedef enum` in C.

I followed the following link, but there are two answers:
[c, obj c enum without tag or identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414188/c-obj-c-enum-without-tag-or-identifier)

LearnCocos2D says that, *"there's no gain to use hex numbers and in particular there's no point in starting the hex numbers with a through f (10 to 15). "*

Sulthan says that, *"Hexadecimal numbers are commonly used when the integer is a binary mask"*. I searched for binary mask and came to understand that, its a technique used in bitmap gaming from following link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)

If sulthan is right, kindly help me understand it.

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I created this as new question.

Comment: To understand why you would use hexadecimal in an enum, you need to understand why you would use hexadecimal for anything. There's really nothing special about a typedef enum.

Comment: Hexadecimal might be used because it can be more readable to programmers, in the right context, than decimal, though to beginners it might seem *less* readable until they become familiar with hex. You mention bit masks, which are more easily converted from hex to binary in the mind, than from decimal, and somehow it makes their intended use more obvious: as masks rather than values. For example, the mask might isolate specific bits in a processor register, rather than being a value used for computation.

Comment: A _downside_ to using hexadecimal notation occurs when using a hex value outside the `int` range.  With 4-byte `int/unsigned`: `0x80000000` is UB as it violates an "enumeration constant shall be an integer constant expression that has a value representable as an `int`." even though it looks OK.  Yet most compilers handle this in the usual hoped-for manner.

Comment: @chux yes, in MSVC's `limits.h` they have `#define INT_MIN (-2147483647 - 1)`

Comment: @chux: It's not just undefined behavior, it's a constraint violation; any conforming compiler must at least warn about it. (gcc apparently doesn't warn about this by default. gcc is not a conforming C compiler by default.)

Comment: @WeatherVane: The value of `INT_MIN` is not the point. `0x80000000` is a positive value. If `int` is 32 bits, then it's of type `unsigned int` (because it exceeds `INT_MAX`).

Comment: @KeithThompson perhaps my point was poorly stated. MSVC does not use `#define INT_MIN (-2147483648)` because the negated value starts from a positive value that cannot be represented by 32-bit `int`, which is what I thought chux wrote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a bit mask it helps to look at values in binary since that is the level needed for a bit mask. And each enum value typically only sets a single bit.

So the enum values would be set (in binary) to `00001`, `00010`, `00100`, `01000`, `10000`, etc.

Those same values in decimal would be: `1`, `2`, `4`, `8`, `16`, etc.

And in hex they would be `0x01`, `0x02`, `0x04`, `0x08`, `0x10`, etc.

It's really just a matter of preference but since hexadecimal is a power of 2, it better relates to binary than decimal does. This makes it slightly clearer that the values represent bit mask values.

Answer (score 1):

The example in the linked question (not quoted in this question) is:

```
enum {
    easySprite      = 0x0000000a,
    mediumSprite    = 0x0000000b,
    hardSprite      = 0x0000000c,
    backButton      = 0x0000000d,
    magneticSprite  = 0x0000000e,
    magneticSprite2 = 0x0000000f
};
```

This creates an *anonymous* enumerated type; you can't define objects of the type. So in effect, the only thing the declaration does is define a set of `int` constants (enumeration constants are always of type `int`), and specify their values in hexadecimal.

This is arguably an abuse of the `enum` construct, which is mainly intended to create types, but it's the only real way to define integer constants without using macros. (`const int easySprite = 0x0000000a;` doesn't make `easySprite` a constant expression.)

The first value is `0xa` (decimal 10), and the other values are in sequential order.

This:

```
enum {
    easySprite      = 10,
    mediumSprite    = 11,
    hardSprite      = 12,
    backButton      = 13,
    magneticSprite  = 14,
    magneticSprite2 = 15
};
```

would mean exactly the same thing. For that matter, so would this, though it's less explicit:

```
enum {
    easySprite = 10,
    mediumSprite,   
    hardSprite,     
    backButton,     
    magneticSprite, 
    magneticSprite2
};
```

So why use hexadecimal? My guess is that the values of `easySprite`, `mediumSprite` et al are defined in some interface (the linked question mentions OpenGL), and for whatever reason it's convenient to define the values in hexadecimal. Perhaps these values are bitwise-anded with some other values, forming a bit pattern whose low-order 4 bits specify the kind of sprite and the other bits specify other information. Writing `0x0000000a` rather than the equivalent `0xa` is probably intended to make it clear that it's meant to be (part of) a full 32-bit value. It's impossible to be sure without seeing the context.

In any case, there's certainly nothing wrong with using hexadecimal here, and given the context it may well be clearer than the equivalent decimal.

(A Google search for "OpenGL magneticSprite" only gets three or so hits, so I doubt that this is part of the OpenGL specification. A Google search for `mediumSprite` turns up a lot of information about soft drinks.)

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete rmaddy's answer, an alternative writing to make bitmask values more visible without hexadecimal numbers can be:

```
typedef enum
{
    // empty bitmask

    empty_mask = 0,

    // bitmask values

    first_bit   = 1 << 0,
    second_bit  = 1 << 1,
    third_bit   = 1 << 2,

    // bitwise combinations

    both_first_and_second = first_bit | second_bit
} My_enum;
```

The shift operator `<<` removes the need to interpret hexadecimal values.
Combinations can be declared after the "core" values.